# TTL on Hazelcast queue

Tags: queue, hazelcast, ttl

I want to set time-to-live on Hazelcast queue messages, i.e to evict eldest message in the queue after X amount of time. How do I configure the queue?

ps. I noticed the setEmptyQueueTtl method in the QueueConfig class, but that is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no TTL setting for the items in the queue, however sounds like you could also make use of [Ringbuffers](https://docs.hazelcast.org//docs/3.10.5/manual/html-single/index.html#ringbuffer), which has a global ttl setting for items, have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set TTL for a queue in Hazelcast for now.